# Unknown column 'G.Id' in 'on clause'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting `SQL Error (1054): Unknown column 'G.Id' in 'on clause'`.

What is wrong and how can be solved?

```
SELECT E.Id, E.Nome, A.login AS Username, E.Departamento, E.Funcao, E.Telefone, E.Fax, E.Email, A.previlegio AS Perfil, G.Nome
FROM Grupos G, Equipa E
INNER JOIN Acesso AS A 
ON A.id = E.IdAcesso
INNER JOIN Grupos_has_Equipa AS H
ON H.Grupos_Id = G.Id
WHERE E.Id = '1977' 
AND H.Grupo_Principal = "sim"
```

Comment: Don't mix implicit joins and explicit joins!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot mix implicit and explicit joins in a single query.

So the solution is to rewrite

```
FROM Grupos G, Equipa E
```

part to

```
FROM Grupos G INNER JOIN Equipa E
```

PS: I also don't see a join condition that ties `E` and `G` tables. I bet you're getting a cartesian product as a result.